# SQL database questions

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

So I have a couple questions that I would like to have cleared up for me. I have searched all over the internet for a month trying to find an answer to these questions. I really want to learn SQL and understand how the language interacts with its database. So here are a couple questions that I have had.

1. My understanding is that there is MySQL and other software applications that help you interact with your database. What are some other applications that could let me interact with my database?
2. If I am using MySQL where is the data being stored? On my computer or on a database somewhere else?
3. Where can I go to get a free SQL server and interact with it using an oracle application to interact with my database?
4. Can I store files and images in an SQL server?
5. So, lets say I have an SQL database and it has TONS of traffic running through it. What would I do to split the servers up, but still have then interact with each other? Would I create a database that tells where to send that data?
6. I know that Oracle, Microsoft, etc. have free SQL servers. Can somebody point me in the right direction? I am not exactly sure where to go to actually put my tables and such on a database. I do have the application however.

I have tons of other questions, but I will search as hard as I can for those. Thanks you for your response in the advance.

Comment: you said that "[you] have searched all over the internet for a month trying to find an answer to these questions". Seriously ?

Comment: If you've searched for a month without finding answers for these questions you really need to work on your search skills. You could pretty much type in each of your question in a search engine and get hundreds or more answers back...

Comment: @Drew A month was a bit of an exaggeration, but still.

Comment: ok then. Then I will throw one into the #1 bucket: I use an SSH client on my Android to get into remote mysql servers. Good luck bud

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. My understanding is that there is MySQL and other software applications that help you interact with your database. What are some other applications that could let me interact with my database?

> MySQL , SQL Server , Oracle are softwares to be precise
>   Relational Database management systems RDBMS, they Manage (Store, retrieve ,
>   modify) data for you.

2. If I am using MySQL where is the data being stored? On my computer or on a database somewhere else?

> Data will be stored in a database, database is really a file on your computer's
>   file system but you will not directly work with the actual physical
>   file, you will only work with the RDBMS and the RDBMS will manage that
>   file for you.

3. Where can I go to get a free SQL server and interact with it using an oracle application to interact with my database?

> SQL Server Express is a free version.

4. Can I store files and images in an SQL server?

> Yes in SQL Server you have the ability of storing files/documents using a feature
>   called `FILESTREAM`.

5. So, lets say I have an SQL database and it has TONS of traffic running through it. What would I do to split the servers up, but still have then interact with each other? Would I create a database that tells where to send that data?

> For load balancing SQL Server has a feature called `Replication`

6. I know that Oracle, Microsoft, etc. have free SQL servers. Can somebody point me in the right direction? I am not exactly sure where to go to actually put my tables and such on a database.

> Download link for [`Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Comment: If I can be a little picky… NoSQL is not an RDBMS.

Comment: is it not opsss cheers thanks for pointing this out, I thought it was, I have corrected it anyway  :)

Comment: Quick question, I am using SQL developer from Oracle and when I open a new connection and create a database, all that is stored on their databases but the some is stored on mine?

Answer (score 2):

1) I think you might be getting the actual database software and the user interfaces confused for example MySQL is a piece of database software that manages the data stores retrieves it etc. phpMyAdmin is a GUI that you can use to interface with MySQL rather that writing SQL queries. There are other variants of SQL like SQL*Plus and i'm sure there are phpMyAdmin equivalents for all of them however I have only ever used them with the command line. Another alternative is something like MongoDB which is a noSQL database.

2) The data is stored wherever the database is installed. You could run it on a local server. LAMP (linux), WAMP(windows) or MAMP(mac) is the easiest way to get this set up. again look on youtube 100s of tutorials on this

3) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html I havent fully looked into this I must admit

I wont bother carrying on because M.Ali has posted a very good answers to the rest of the questions

Comment: upvotes for deciding not to write a Homerian epic :>

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can help you with this:

> 1. My understanding is that there is MySQL and other software applications that help you interact with your database. What are some other applications that could let me interact with my database?

MySQL, SQL-Server and others are Relational Database Management Systems (RDBMS for short); they are database software that help you store your data, following the relational model (columns are fields, rows are data-tuples, etcétera). RDBMSs handle the task of storing, updating and retrieving the data, but they are not, by themselves, "applications". An application (as I understand it) is a program designed to interact with a user, and sits between the user and the data stored in the database. So, this is a little schematic of what is going on

```
Database        Application                   User
--------        -----------                   ----
Stores data     Receives user input/output    Interacts with the app
                and sends / updates / reads
                data to/from the database
```

> 2. If I am using MySQL where is the data being stored? On my computer or on a database somewhere else?

It's stored in the computer where it's installed (in the simplest configuration). Each RDBMS may handle the data storage differently, but the bottom line is that the RDBMS "worries" about the data storage, and let's you handle the data with a "simple" and "consistent" language (most cases, using the particular SQL "dialect" of the RDBMS)

> 3. Where can I go to get a free SQL server and interact with it using an oracle application to interact with my database?

What do you mean by "Oracle application"? Oracle, as far as I know, is a RDBMS. If you want to get the free SQL-Server, go to the Microsoft Site and download it.

> 4. Can I store files and images in an SQL server?

Yes

> 5. So, lets say I have an SQL database and it has TONS of traffic running through it. What would I do to split the servers up, but still have then interact with each other? Would I create a database that tells where to send that data?

Many RDBMSs have tools to handle this (partitions, replication, etcetera). Read the documentation.

> 6. I know that Oracle, Microsoft, etc. have free SQL servers. Can somebody point me in the right direction? I am not exactly sure where to go to actually put my tables and such on a database. I do have the application however.

Google around. MySQL is free, PostgreSQL is free. SQL server has a free version. Also, Google around for a good SQL tutorial (I'd recommend you to learn how to use MySQL, because it's one of the easiest ones).

---

You should narrow your research. If you want a free, fully featured RDBMS, I'd recommend you use MySQL or PostgreSQL (I don't use SQL server, but that's just me). Also, if you want to develop applications, you should learn how to develop with other languages. Most (if not all) languages have libraries designed to interact with databases.

Answer (score 0):

I would start here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp. W3Schools does a decent job explaining the basics. From there you could branch out to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-rdbms-concepts.htm. A Google search from there would suffice to answer any other questions you may have.

Comment: Thank you for the links to tutorials. I have seen these before though, but still, thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. MySQL, Oracle, and SQL Server are some that are used to create SQL databases.
2. MySql can be stored locally or on a host (godaddy).
3. MySql is free. I believe you have to pay to use the others.
4. Yes.
5. When you get to that point, you'll want to either hire someone, or work on databases and web traffic till you understand a good amount.
6. I would check with Godaddy, or some other web hosting site, and they can provide free advice.

Comment: Thanks for answering